# PhoneGap MultiPlatform Application

Tags: mobile, cordova, multiplatform

Im wondering if i want to use phonegap to create a multiplatform application do i need to create a project for each mobile platform or I create one standard project and then phonegap will package that for different platforms.

 whats the easiest way to create a multiplatform app using phonegap. I checked phonegap wiki but they explain for each platform, i want to know if theres a way to do them all together in one project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build on each platform. If you don't want to do that, they offer a Build service that purports to build your app on each platform for you. See https://build.phonegap.com/ for more info.